# Graphical Xubuntu session get freezed during startup

Tags: xubuntu, startup, freeze, citrix

my Xubuntu is freezing during startup of a graphical session:

```
uname -a
Linux ******-Latitude-5420 5.8.0-63-generic #71~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 17:46:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[My last boot log](https://pastebin.com/G9vh0Hdd)

Maybe it can help to troubleshoot: very lastly I did some big changes: create/delete/recreate a new partition ; change root and user passwords ; stop encrypting the /home/user repertory

Thank you for your help. When the graphical session has freezed, I can still Ctrl+Alt+F2 to reach a terminal and launch commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it! :D There was another big change I had just done: I had installed the Citrix client (icaclient-***.deb). To uninstall it gave me back my system.

Comment: If you use the tick in the top left corner of the answer, you can mark the question as solved by this answer.